# Can I set state of imported component in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> I want to set state of imported component. Something like

```
import ProductListing from '../components/ProductListing';

    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    ProductListing = new ProductListing();
    ProductListing.state = {someVariable : 'hello'}; 
    }
```

Comment: What is your use case? You probably want to pass down the data as props to the component in the render method.

Comment: Actually I want solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099422/can-i-pass-state-at-the-time-of-navigator-dispatch-method-calling-in-react-nativ
OR
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087325/react-native-set-state-from-drawer-navigator-to-other-component
So I am trying to be more specific I know how to pass states between parent and child. But want to send a state on content component of drawer navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Send data as props from the component where you want to use and inside the state of that component use it. 
Example:

```
import UserInfo from './userInfo.js' 
class UserDetail extends React.Component {
  render()
    {
            return(
       <UserInfo  myNewState= {//define your state here} /> 
       )

    }
}

And inside UserInfo use this: 

.... 
state= {this.props.myNewState}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But sorry this is not the solution of my problem please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087325/react-native-set-state-from-drawer-navigator-to-other-component and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099422/can-i-pass-state-at-the-time-of-navigator-dispatch-method-calling-in-react-nativ

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is just to update the state of the child component in your case it is ProductListing. So you can do these steps

Create ProductListing as a react class so that you can create a reference for that

```
class ProductListing extends Component (){
state = {
    items: []
}

updateStateItems = (data) => {
    this.setState({ items: data })
}
render() {
    return(
        // your render method code code
    )
}}
```

import ProductListing in your parent class and create a reference for that and in componentDidMount using the reference call function`updateStateItems` with data that you want to set in ProductListing state.

```
import ProductListing from './ProductListing'
class ParentClass extends Component (){
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

componentDidMount(){
   // here use that reference to pass the data that you want to set in state
   this.ref.updateStateItems(data)}
render() {
    return(
        <div>
           <ProductListing 
            // to create a reference of product listing
            ref={(ref) => { this.ref = ref }} 
           /> 
        </div>
    )
}}
```